# Sparse matrix - key-value db?

Tags: nosql

I have a huge sparse matrix ( 10^9 rows, 10^6 cols, density < 0.03% ), where each row has at least one nonzero column, but some column may contain only zeros. The cells are decimal numbers > 0.

I am looking for some db (preferably key-value) that can retrieve whole row or whole column as fast as possible. Also, I don't need to do any analytics in the DB.

I've come across [SciDB](http://www.paradigm4.com/) which should be fast with multidimensional data, but I am afraid it is too complex for my needs.

Also, another option is to use SQL db ( probably Postgres ) but that is a bit slow and can't be scaled as easily as most NoSQL ( I expect fast row increase in matrix ).

So my biggest hope is some key-value storage, but I am not sure how to represent the matrix.

- Using [CRS format](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~dongarra/etemplates/node373.html) - but I have no idea how to implement it using key-value store.
- Maybe something like { key, key, value } and have indexed both keys, but I am not sure if this is even possible. - So far I've found some clues about secondary index, but I can't imagine how would it look like.

I have some experience with SQL databases but almost none with NoSQL :(

Comment: If you think PostgreSQL is either slow or can't be scaled easily, you are quite mistaken.

Comment: I am prepared to be enlighten :) I do not require strict consistency and speed is critical for me, so i thought that some NoSQL would perform better. I agree that PostgreSQL would provide valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting use case...

What makes your problem complex for a DB is your access pattern. Looks like you want to access both by row as well as column. General purpose DBs are generally either row-oriented storage (mostly) or column-oriented storage which will be their most efficient mode of access. They will support the access other way round also (for e.g column based access in a row-oriented storage) but it will not be most efficient for obvious reasons.

If you have a access pattern (row/column) which is way more frequent than the other, you can pick the appropriate DB. If both the access patterns are equally likely, you may consider storing the information in a redundant way. i.e Both the matrix and the transpose of it. As you said the density of the matrix is 0.03%, the overhead may not be too much. You can make the call here.

Coming to the DBs, most of the noSQL DBs offer a flex schema. i.e you do not need to define the schema(columns) upfront and the columns can be optional. For this reason, I think a noSQL DB will be a better fit for this sparse matrix use case. When you query for the row, you will get only the columns which has values in it. You will get the column name along with the result.

The CRS format, while it is great on its own for space saving, it does not fit so well in a DB schema. You will have to handle the access from you application logic. In other words, you will not be really using the row-based access mechanism of DB.

Another option is to use a modified CRS format. For every row, you can store the matrix column values as a series of (column,column value) pairs. You can store this as a single value in a single column of the database. This will avoid the per-column overhead of the DBs. However, you have to do extra processing to decode the matrix columns in your application.

Which DB ? I dont want to pick a name. I would be starting an opinion war. Please do this research separately.

Comment: Wow, that actually helped a lot! Thanks :) I think that adding an application logic is out of question. I will try the transpose matrix variant with some key-value store. Could you possibly recommend some db that is not strictly in memory?

Answer (score 0):

I'm puzzled as to why you think SciDB would be too complex? (Full disclosure ... I work for Paradigm4, so what's familiar to me might not be so obvious to others).

Your basic data structure (your array) would look something like this:

```
CREATE ARRAY MyData 
<
    data : double 
>
[ I=0:999999999,60000,0, J=0:999999,60000,0 ];
```

That's 10^9 rows by 10^6 columns, divided into "chunks" of 60K x 60K (working on your 0.03% sparsity factor) to average about 1,000,000 cells per chunk. I am assuming that you don't want to track all of those zeroes; just the non-zero data cells.

Your queries are:

"Get me row I=1000..."

```
slice ( MyData, I, 1000 );
```

"Get me column J=1000..."

```
slice ( MyData, J, 1000 );
```

The way SciDB works is that it clusters the array's contents into blocks where co-local cells are kept in the same block. So queries like the ones above only touch those blocks that contain the rows or columns you want.

If you want to do something like ...

"Compute the number of row values in common for the columns J=1000 and J=2000 ..."

```
aggregate ( 
    join ( slice ( MyData, J, 1000 ), slice ( MyData, J, 2000 ) ),
    count(*)
);
```

I suspect that you're doing something with a very, very big sparse graph. That's a problem space we're also very interested in working on. Contact us, or visit the forums. I'm also curious to understand the parameters of the problem you're going after. In our experience, folk generally don't want to just look up rows and columns; they want to compute things about them. Simple counts, similarity metrics and distance functions, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this looks really straight forward :) Is the speed comparable to the solution (transposed matrix) proposed by @sunil? I will make sure to visit the forums! BTW this is actually one hell of a PR :D

Comment: I would take the approach of actually measuring things rather than taking as gospel some hand-waving in a forum. :)  Shouldn't be hard. Put up a realistically scaled physical cluster, stand up the two alternatives, create a (synthetic) data set, implement a couple of representative operations, and see.

Comment: @plumber is right in saying that the decision should be based on experimental data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the NoSQL Composite Key Indexing modeling technique. In a key value pair, make your keys actually represent a hierarchical nested sorting knowledge. The result is sort of a denormalized matrix, which if sparsely populated, is much more condensed than an actual multidimensional array where any matrix index that does not have a value does not have a key/value pair.

example

Comment: Will you actually provide the example?  +1 if you do...